Eggplant Seed collection and immediate(ish) usage
Its spring here (Auckland NZ - Southern Hemisphere), and I have an overripe eggplant I want to harvest seeds from to grow - but I'm unsure of the steps between "take the seeds out the eggplant" and "put in ground/put on heating mat" -

Can I grow Eggplants from freshly harvested seeds?

If not, I assume I need to dry them out - Can I just dry them out for a few days and then try and get them to germinate or do I need to wait a while?   Do I need to put them in the fridge/otherwise stratify them?

Am I better off direct sowing the seeds or putting them in a damp towel in a bag on a heated bed to encourage the seeds to germinate?   (Daytime temperatures are 14-20, nighttime temperatures 8 - 17 depending on cloud cover)



For my fellow philistines, that is 57-69F daytime, 46-62F nighttime temperatures.

Isn't a cold treatment for cold-weather plants (apples), not heat addicts like eggplant?

@YosefBaskin Good thought and I confused myself as  I store all my seeds in the fridge - but do the seeds need a "dormancy" period?

A germination test takes a minute to prepare couple of weeks to wait out.

@vorac I am doing said test, but it would have been really convenient to not need to.I have reason to believe I can use fresh seeds, but its to early to be sure. (Also a lot longer then a minute to prepare. I spent a while getting the seeds out)

Germinating Eggplant Seeds
Your question is really several questions, but I think I can answer all of them well. I've grown many varieties of eggplant from seed.


Can I grow Eggplants from freshly harvested seeds?

Yes. You can grow eggplant from fresh seeds. In fact, you don't even need to remove them as you have done. In an overripe eggplant the seeds will sometimes germinate before you cut it open. It's a nightshade, (Solanaceae family) and similar to tomatoes, you can plant very thin slices in shallow soil that will often do better than seeds that have been removed. The remnants of fruit flesh in decomposition contribute compounds that naturally aid in germination. A very light spray of hydrogen peroxide at this time will contribute oxygen and reduce pathogens.
There's a very interesting study about it here (by the NIH) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6930571/


If not, I assume I need to dry them out - Can I just dry them out for
a few days and then try and get them to germinate or do I need to wait
a while? Do I need to put them in the fridge/otherwise stratify them?

No,no,no
Don't dry them out. Don't put them in the fridge. Don't scarify them (what I assume you meant when you said "stratify" them). Stratification can involve prepping them with heat or cold. So, yes to heat and no to cold. Eggplant need to be kept warm before, during, and after germination. For germination, 27–30 °C is best, but definitely not below 20°C


Am I better off direct sowing the seeds or putting them in a damp
towel in a bag on a heated bed to encourage the seeds to germinate?
(Daytime temperatures are 14-20, nighttime temperatures 8 - 17
depending on cloud cover)

No, and Yes.
It's too early for direct sowing outdoors. Start them indoors and only put them outside when the weather gets warmer than it is indoors. Put some of them between two layers of moist paper towel, and put some others near the surface of a thin layer of clean moist soil. Keep them warm, keep them moist, and keep them covered. You can rinse the ones on the paper towel every few days.
They don't need light at first, but they will after the first set of leaves have sprouted. That's when you should put them near a window.  When a root begins to develop (about 1 cm) then I transfer them into those little yogurt cups individually with my best soil (with holes in the bottom of course). If the root has embedded itself into the paper towel, then separate them by cutting that portion of paper towel while leaving it attached to the root.
If you want to avoid all the fuss, there is a similar method explained in this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RX5CANe5KE&t=24s Personally, I like playing with them and watching the germination, and my method takes up a lot less indoor space, but I especially like how the gardener in the video uses worm castings. I'm a big fan of that.
The only other important tip I should mention is to make sure they don't get too soggy. They have to be kept moist, but don't let them soak. Good luck!

Hi Scott, welcome to the gardening site! Great nightshade knowledge. I edited the questions you were answering into your answer as quotes to make it a little easier to read, I hope you don't mind.

Thanks! I thought it was a cool bot until I noticed your comment.

I don't think my test will be completed before the bounty runs out (and it may be that my seeds are not fertile) but in theory it may best to directly plant the fresh seeds, as by drying them out they enter dormancy and take longer to start growing.
My reference here is a snippet I found online from the book "The Complete GUide to Saving Seeds" by Robert Gough and Cheryl Moore-Gough which says, under the Section "To Dry or Not to dry?"  *If you itend to plant the seeds soon after cleaning take care not to dry them, because this may induce dormancy that does not exist in some fresh seeds."  Of-course, this does not talk specifically about Eggplant seeds.

"...may...in some..." The most frustrating words in garden literature.  Is the book worth getting, or should I try another?

Did that germination test come to completion?  Did the fresh seeds germinate?

@mackm total disaster - nothing germinated.  I expect I harvested the seeds before they ripened.

An eggplant is meant to be eaten and the seeds deposited with the eater's dung - no drying happens. Just dig them out of the fruit and plant them directly if you want them immediately. Drying is really just for seeds you want to keep for a long while.
